# How do I re-format datetime in mysql?

Tags: php, mysql, datetime

**QUESTION 1 :** I am using datetime to store the date and time in MySQL. I use MySQL Now() function to insert datetime. How do I store the date using a different format? From : Year-Month-Day Hour:Mins:Sec to : Day-Month-Year Hour:Mins:Sec.

**QUESTION 2 :** How can I retrieve only a specified part (day, month, year, etc.) of the date stored above?

Comment: Question 1: see answers. Question 2: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html

Comment: Might as well ask how to park your car on the ceiling of your garage. You don't choose how to store a date in mysql, you only choose how to present it.

Comment: @Marc B, thank you for correctiion :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You did not understand, mysql accept date format only in `yyyy-mm-dd`. you can not change the standard of mysql.

Although you can retrieve date in different format using mysql in-built functions.

Look at the [date and time](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html) functions of mysql you can retrieve date in any format then why do you need to change the storage format.

Comment: oh, ok if that is the case then while retrieving i would like to change the format, how do i do it?

Comment: @ibrahim: I have given the link in my answer that is date_format

Answer (score 0):

Use datetime type and date_format() to show dates in the way you like. It's wrong to store them as strings.

Answer (score 0):

You can't really choose how you want to **store** datetime, you can only choose how to format it when you retrieve it, which is what I think you wanted. MySQL has its own internal mechanisms on how it stores the datetime and similar formats.

In your query where you select the datetime column, you can specify formatting options or you can use PHP's DateTime class to output the given date in any format you want to the browser.

Assuming you want to format the date mysql stored directly in your query, you can use something like this:

```
SELECT CONCAT(MONTH(NOW()), '.', DAY(now()), '.', YEAR(now()));
```

In the example provided, you can swap NOW() for the column that stores datetime in your table, it should be easy to do that by yourself, I assume you got enough experience.

For retrieving individual values, such as minutes or seconds of a given date - you almost had it yourself, the syntax is

```
SELECT MINUTE(NOW());
SELECT SECOND(NOW());
```

You can also use MICROSECOND, DAY, MONTH, YEAR - just pass the proper datetime and MySQL does the rest.

Answer (score 0):

As noted before, it's not a good idea to change the way datetime is stored (messes up ordering by date for one thing), but what you can do, is change the outputted date, like so :

```
$oldDate = "2011-12-10 10:22:32
$newDate = date('d-m-Y G:i:s', strtotime($oldDate));
echo $newDate
10-12-2011 10:22:32
```

and for your second question, it could be :

```
$newDate = date('d/m - Y', strtotime($oldDate));
echo $newDate
10/12 - 2011
```

To alter the output, read [PHP Date()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php)

This is one way, but can also be done directly from the SQL Query with datetime().

Hope this answers your question...